# Facebook realtime api for feed

Tags: java, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have set up realtime feed update for user. So whenever a user comments or likes something, I get a update request from facebook.

```
{
  object='user', 
  entry=[{
          uid='1372299847',
          id='1372299847',
          time=1368760855, 
          changedFields=[feed]
         }]
}
```

But this doesn't tell me what the update exactly was. I have to read that user's feed and see what is the new change and process it. If I get the id, then I can just request for that object and process it rather than reading his feed and getting the changes.

Is there any way to get what exactly was changed(id of the comment or status)?

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) says that you have to get the actual changeset via Graph API or FQL query. The notification you get tells you only the concerned user's ID.